# Problema para mostrar datos de manera correcta en consulta SQL en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Buen día. Tengo una tabla en Access llamada `Cartera` compuesta de la siguiente manera

```
idCartera, codigo, nombre, categoria, mes, idAnio
```

(El campo mes se llena del 1 al 12 representando a cada mes).. Y por ejemplo tengo estos registros

```
1, 123, "Juan", "A1", 1, 12
2, 456, "Maria", "B", 1, 12
3, 789, "Pepe", "A2", 1, 12

4, 123, "Juan", "A1", 2, 12
5, 456, "Maria", "A1", 2, 12
6, 789, "Pepe", "A2", 2, 12
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar los registros que cumplan con un rango de categorias **Pero hay un caso especial:** En el caso de la categoria `A1`. Si en el mes anterior la categoria es `A1` y en el mes actual sigue siendo `A1`, **no debo mostrarla**. Pero si en el mes anterior es cualquier categoria diferente de `A1` y en el mes actual la categoria es `A1`, **si debo mostrala**

Por ejemplo, Ubicándonos en la consulta del mes de Febrero, los resultados que deseo obtener son

```
5, 456, "Maria", "A1", 2, 12
6, 456, "Pepe", "A2", 2, 12
```

Por el momento la consulta que tengo es:

```
SELECT c.idCartera, c.codigo, c.nombre, [c].[mes]-1 AS mes_anterior
FROM cartera AS c INNER JOIN cartera AS d ON (c.codigo = d.codigo) AND (d.mes = c.mes-1) AND (c.idAnio = d.idAnio)
WHERE c.mes = 2 AND c.categoria IN ('A1','A2','B')
```

> (Para aclarar: Lo de "mes_anterior" lo utilizo para hacer una resta en
>   otra consulta)

Pero esta consulta no cumple con el caso especial que tengo, en vez de eso me muestra todos los registros con categoria `A1` sin importar que en el mes anterior la categoria es la misma. O sea que me devuelve:

```
4, 123, "Juan", "A1", 2, 12
5, 456, "Maria", "A1", 2, 12
6, 789, "Pepe", "A2", 2, 12
```

Entonces mi pregunta es de que manera puedo poner ese caso especial o "condicion" en mi consulta.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.idCartera, c.codigo, c.nombre, [c].[mes]-1 AS mes_anterior
FROM #cartera AS c 
    INNER JOIN #cartera AS d ON (c.codigo = d.codigo) AND (d.mes = c.mes-1) AND (c.idAnio = d.idAnio)
WHERE c.mes = 2 AND ((d.categoria <> 'A1' and c.categoria = 'A1') or c.categoria <> 'A1') AND c.categoria IN ('A1','A2','B')
```

Diria que esta es la consulta que pides, en esta consulta tiene que tener que si la categoria del "mes en curso" es A1 el anterior es distinto de A1 o que directamente este mes sea distinto de A1, revisalo a ver que tal

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias